# ParseGlob: What is the pattern to parse all templates recursively within a directory?

Tags: go, go-templates

```
Template.ParseGlob("*.html") //fetches all html files from current directory.
Template.ParseGlob("**/*.html") //Seems to only fetch at one level depth
```

Im not looking for a "Walk" solution. Just want to know if this is possible. I don't quite understand what "pattern" this expects. if i can get an explanation about the pattern used by ParseGlob that would be great too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [code `text/template/helper.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/helper.go?s=2861:2910#L75) mentions

```
 // The pattern is processed by filepath.Glob and must match at least one file.
```

[`filepath.Glob()`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) says that "the syntax of patterns is the same as in [`Match`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match)"

> Match returns true if name matches the shell file name pattern.

The [implementation of Match()](http://golang.org/src/pkg/path/filepath/match.go?s=1235:1293#L34) doesn't seem to treat '`**`' differently, and only consider '`*`' as matching any sequence of non-Separator characters.
That would mean '`**`' is equivalent to '`*`', which in turn would explain why the match works at one level depth only.

Answer (score 2):

So, since the [`ParseGlob`](https://godoc.org/html/template#ParseGlob) can't load templates recursively we have to use [`path/filepath.Walk`](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Walk) function. But this way gives more opportunities.

https://gist.github.com/logrusorgru/abd846adb521a6fb39c7405f32fec0cf