# Can template.ParseGlob() parse templates in subdirectories?

Tags: templates, go

To clean up the template folder I would like to save common templates inside a subfolder. Currently I've the following file structure:

```
main.go
templates/index.tpl            # Main template for the main page
templates/includes/head.tpl
templates/includes/footer.tpl
```

`head.tpl` and `footer.tpl` will be called within `index.tpl`, which looks like this:

```
{{ template "head" . }}
    <h1>My content</h1>
{{ template "footer" .}}
```

Furthermore the files are parsed using `template.ParseGlob()`. Here's an excerpt from `main.go`:

```
var views = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("src/templates/**/*"))

func Render(rw http.ResponseWriter, temp string, data interface{}) {
    err := views.ExecuteTemplate(rw, temp, data)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(rw, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func Index(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    Render(rw, "index.tpl", nil)
}
```

Everytime I open my browser I get this  error message: `html/template: "index.tpl" is undefined`.

Is it possible, that `index.tpl` is ignored with this glob pattern? 
I found [this](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/golang-nuts/137tj3axkn/go-nuts-template-parseglob-pattern-to-parse-all-files-in-a-directory-recursively) similar question, but the answers present only a work around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ParseGlob: What is the pattern to parse all templates recursively within a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25745701/parseglob-what-is-the-pattern-to-parse-all-templates-recursively-within-a-direc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it cannot.

The documentation is pretty clear here: Globbing for `template.ParseGlob` works like in `filepath.Glob` and `filepath.Glob` uses the syntax of `filepath.Match` (https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Match) which has no `**` for a deep match.

(It *really* helps to read the documentation carefully.)

Comment: pattern:
 { term }
term:
 '*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
 '?'         matches any single non-Separator character
 '[' [ '^' ] { character-range } ']'
             character class (must be non-empty)
 c           matches character c (c != '*', '?', '\\', '[')
 '\\' c      matches character c

character-range:
 c           matches character c (c != '\\', '-', ']')
 '\\' c      matches character c
 lo '-' hi   matches character c for lo <= c <= hi

Comment: what does it even mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can load multiple subdirectories this way. Here we ignore if subdirectories do not exist. But we want to make sure that the first directory with templates can be loaded.

```
func ParseTemplates() (*template.Template, error) {
    templateBuilder := template.New("")
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*/*/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    return templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*.tmpl")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This response was a more useful than the marked answer.