# Golang: Parse all templates in directory and subdirectories?

Tags: go

This is my directory structure:

```
app/
  template/
    layout/
      base.tmpl
    index.tmpl
```

`template.ParseGlob("*/*.tmpl")` parses `index.tmpl` but not `base.tmpl` in the `layout` subdirectory. Is there a way to parse all templates recursively?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can template.ParseGlob() parse templates in subdirectories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309830/can-template-parseglob-parse-templates-in-subdirectories)

Comment: @icza I agree with the possible duplicate, but it doesn't exactly provide an answer on how to work around this which may be why these duplicate questions are appearing.

Answer (score 21):

Not without implementing your own function to do it, I've been using something like this

```
func ParseTemplates() *template.Template {
    templ := template.New("")
    err := filepath.Walk("./views", func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if strings.Contains(path, ".html") {
            _, err = templ.ParseFiles(path)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
            }
        }

        return err
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return templ
}
```

This will parse all your templates then you can render them by calling their names e.g.

`template.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home", nil)`

Comment: A shame something like that isn't in the standard library. Good thing it isn't hard to implement, though.

Comment: This doesn't work very well if several directories contain files with the same name. Using ParseFiles, the template's name is obtained from the base name of the file path; this might cause name conflicts.

Answer (score 18):

Datsik's answer has the drawback that there are name collision issues when several directories contain many templates. If two templates in different directories have the same filename it won't work properly: only the second of them will be usable.

This is caused by the implementation of template.ParseFiles, so we can solve it by avoiding template.ParseFiles. Here's a modified walk algorithm that does this by using template.Parse directly instead.

```
func findAndParseTemplates(rootDir string, funcMap template.FuncMap) (*template.Template, error) {
    cleanRoot := filepath.Clean(rootDir)
    pfx := len(cleanRoot)+1
    root := template.New("")

    err := filepath.Walk(cleanRoot, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, e1 error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() && strings.HasSuffix(path, ".html") {
            if e1 != nil {
                return e1
            }

            b, e2 := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
            if e2 != nil {
                return e2
            }

            name := path[pfx:]
            t := root.New(name).Funcs(funcMap)
            _, e2 = t.Parse(string(b))
            if e2 != nil {
                return e2
            }
        }

        return nil
    })

    return root, err
}
```

This will parse all your templates then you can render them by calling their names e.g.

```
template.ExecuteTemplate(w, "a/home.html", nil)
```

Comment: This is a very useful example. Adding to a root template by walking the tree and matching on certain filename patterns and then building template names from them is a great way to organize templates and make their access easy.

Comment: How would this be called? `templates := findAndParseTemplates("templates", ??)`? What's the argument for `template.FuncMaps`?

Comment: The function map is the same as expected by the standard template API. It's a map of function names to function pointers for any custom functions you want; it can be nil I think.

Answer (score 15):

if it is not deeply nested (if you know names of sub-directories beforehand) you can just do this:

```
t := template.Must(template.ParseGlob("template/*.tmpl"))
template.Must(t.ParseGlob("template/layout/*.tmpl"))
```

Then for each sub-directory do the same as for 'layout'

Answer (score 0):

You can load multiple subdirectories this way. Here we ignore if subdirectories do not exist. But we want to make sure that the first directory can be loaded.

```
func ParseTemplates() (*template.Template, error) {
    templateBuilder := template.New("")
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*/*/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    if t, _ := templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*/*.tmpl"); t != nil {
        templateBuilder = t
    }
    return templateBuilder.ParseGlob("/*.tmpl")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a package that solves exactly this problem.

https://github.com/karelbilek/template-parse-recursive

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"

    recurparse "github.com/karelbilek/template-parse-recursive"
)

func main() {
    t, err := recurparse.HTMLParse(
        template.New("templates"), 
        "path/to/templates", 
        "*.html",
    )
   
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    templateUnder := t.Lookup("subdir/subdir/template.html")
    templateUnder.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the answer of pete911 I could create this function to parse all the html templates on multiple subdirectories.

```golang
// parse.go
func ParseHtmlTemplates() *template.Template {
    var directories []string
    var filenames []string

    // Root directory of template files
    root := "./templates"

    // Get all directories on /templates and check if there's repeated files
    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            // Is file
            filename := info.Name()

            hasRepeatedFiles := contains(filenames, filename)
            if hasRepeatedFiles {
                return fmt.Errorf("You can't have repeated template files: %s", filename)
            }

            filenames = append(filenames, filename)
        } else {
            // Is directory
            directories = append(directories, path)
        }

        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    // Create a template for parsing all directories
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseGlob(root + "/*.html"))

    // Parse all directories (minus the root directory)
    for _, path := range directories[1:] {
        pattern := path + "/*.html"
        template.Must(tmpl.ParseGlob(pattern))
    }

    return tmpl
}

// contains private method
func contains(filenames []string, filename string) bool {
    for _, f := range filenames {
        if f == filename {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

// main.go
func main() {
    tmpl = ParseHtmlTemplates()
    if err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, ""); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```